# Loading handlebars.js template from external html file shows nothing

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, mustache

This question is a bit of a stretch of my JS skills, so I might explain it like an idiot.

Here is my JavaScript to get the json from the server, and try to push it into a template:

```
    //Server Interface Start
//Access the web api for The User:
var lucidServer = (function () {
    //global error handler
    $(document).ajaxError(function (event, xhr) {
        alert(xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
    });
    //client Calls
    var getClients = function (id) {
        return $.ajax(clientUrl + "/list/" + id)
    };
    var getClient = function (id) {
        return $.ajax(clientUrl + "/details/" + id)
    };

    //push them out to the world!
    return {
        getClients: getClients,
        getClient: getClient,
    };
}());
//Server Interface End

(function () {
    //list of clients
    var refreshClients = function () {
        lucidServer.getClients(1).done(showAllClients);
    };
    var showAllClients = function (templateInput) {
        var source;
        var template;
        var path = '../Templates/indexTemplates.html'
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            cache: true,
            success: function (data) {
                source = data;
                template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                $('#clientListOutput').html(template(templateInput));
            }
        });
    };
    $(function () {
        refreshClients();
    });
}());
```

GetClients works fine and returns the Json data I am expecting. When I inspect the templateInput it is showing what I expect.

Here is the external template:

```
<script id="clientList" type="text/html">

<div id="clients">
    {{#each client}}
                <span data-id="{{this.iD}}" />
    <div>
        <p>{{this.iD}}</p>
        <p>{{this.name}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
</script>
```

What I am ultimately aiming to do is hold either all my templates in one html file that I can call by script id, or have each template be its own file that I can call. When I run this page nothing is showing up, there's no error or anything. Here is the entire index page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/main.css">
    <script src="../../scripts/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <section id="Application">
        <div id="clientListOutput">
        </div>
        <div id="clientCreateOutput">
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../scripts/libs/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../../scripts/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/libs/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script>
        var freelancerUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAndIntegerId", new { httproute="", controller = "Freelancer"})';
        var clientUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Client"})';
        var projectUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAction", new { httproute="", controller = "Project"})';
        var storyUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("ApiControllerAndIntegerId", new { httproute="", controller = "Story"})';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/serverInterface.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Edit

I changes the way my template looks slightly. Through debugging the js in Chrome tools it is telling me that 'data' is undefined in the ajax success line within showallclients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call template with the data returned from getClient. In you  example the argument to showAllClients is shadowed by the argument in the success callback because you use the same name (data). Change the argument name in showAllClients to something else, and pass it to the template function.

```
(function () {

        //list of clients
        var refreshClients = function () {
           $.when(lucidServer.getClients(1)).done(showAllClients);
        };
        var showAllClients = function (templateInput) {
            var source;
            var template;
            var path = 'Templates/indexTemplates.html'
            $.ajax({
                url: path,
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    source = data;
                    template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                    $('#clientListOutput').html(template(templateInput));
                }
            });
        };

        $(function () {

            refreshClients();
        });
    }());
```

EDIT:

In the template you need to refer to `this` inside the each block:

```
<div id="clients">
    {{#each client}}
                <span data-id="{{this.id}}">
                    <div>
                        <p>{{this.iD}}</p>
                        <p>{{this.name}}</p>
                     ...
                    </div>
        {{/each}}
</div>
```

In your example you use nested iterators, which I'm not sure is supported. Please read [How do I use nested iterators with Mustache.js or Handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203858/how-do-i-use-nested-iterators-with-mustache-js-or-handlebars-js) or [Ember.js / Handlebars nested each iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713833/ember-js-handlebars-nested-each-iterations) for a different approach.

Comment: This is giving me this error: ReferenceError: templateInput is not defined

Comment: You probably need to wrap the call to lucidServer in a when as well, see edits above and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Good call on the .when, makes sense. But it still is not rendering anything. Any ideas?

Comment: In that case you need to start debugging. Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the success callback and verify that the templateInput is as expected, and that the correct template is returned etc. You can use http://getfirebug.com/ or Chrome developer tool to set the breakpoint. More details: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/13/debugging-javascript-with-chrome.aspx

Comment: Yeah I am digging into the chrome dev tools now. It seems like it is not even going inside the functions at all, just skipping over them, and I am getting a lot of undefined errors

Comment: OK. BTW, found another issue with the nested each and missing use of this inside the each block of you template. Added an edit to the answer.

Comment: Very good, I will look into that. For now I just got rid of the nested on. No it is working up until the ajax success function. It is saying data is not defined