# How to compile an external handlebars template without using $.ajax

Tags: handlebars.js

I have 2 files in a very simple web application

The first is a standard index.html and it looks something like the below

```
<body>
<div id="add-stuff"></div>
<script id="the-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" src="some-template.erb.html"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [];
  var source = $("#the-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  $('#add-stuff').html(template(data));
</script>
</body>
```

The second is my handlebars template "some-template.erb.html" and it looks something like the below

```
<table>
{{#each item}}
<tr><td>{{ item.name }}</td></tr>
{{/each}
</table>
```

The problem with the inline javascript I have above is that when I try the ".html()" part it always returns an empty string (as I'm linking in the erb.html file).

I've found a work around that lets me achieve this if I use $.ajax to pull in the template but I'd much prefer something like the above (so I can include the template client side w/out any nested jQuery callbacks).

Is this possible? If not what can I do do improve the $.ajax based approach?

** the ajax based approach that works is shown below **

```
<body>
<div id="add-stuff"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
  url: 'some-template.erb.html',
  cache: true,
  success: function (source) {
    var data = [];
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $('#add-stuff').html(template(data));
  }
});
</script>
</body>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075132/loading-handlebars-js-template-from-external-html-file-shows-nothing/13075301) is a link to the stackoverflow question that showed the $.ajax version in a bit more detail

Comment: The file name is open for debate. I'm doing django development and want a simple way to compile handlebars templates without the extreme of making an ajax call

Answer (score 1):

maybe its already outdated, but I found your question today and I have a suggestion for you or people who are dealing with the same problem. It's not a perfect one, but for small templates an option if you don't want to use ajax.

What do you think about writing the template as string in a variable in an external JS-file and inlcude it via script tag?

template.js

```
var source = '<table>\
          {{#each item}}\
          <tr><td>{{ item.name }}</td></tr>\
          {{/each}';
```

index.html

```
<body>
<div id="add-stuff"></div>
<script src="template.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [];
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  $('#add-stuff').html(template(data));
</script>
</body>
```