# Handlebars.js separating script tags from html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

What is the best way of separating the script tag like the following from inside an html document?

```
<ul class="shoesNav">
 <script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each this}}
       <li class="shoes">
            <a href="/{{name}}">{{name}} -- Price: {{price}} </a>
       </li>
   {{/each}}
 </script> 
</ul>
```

Would it be possible to have something like this or similar?

```
<ul class="shoesNav">
  {{#each this}}
       <li class="shoes">
            <a href="/{{name}}">{{name}} -- Price: {{price}} </a>
       </li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The idea would be to have all the templates in a separate file.

Comment: You could just keep all templates inside the `<head>`. There is no need to embed them within the body itself. Check out pandora.com and see how they implement templates.

Comment: I would like to keep them in a separate file to have a more clear html document. template.js or something like that, however I can't use '.js' because they are not javascript files

Comment: You can have a separate html file called like "Templates.html" or "ProductTemplates.html". Inside those files, you will have standard html, but include the script tags/templates inside. Then just load these html templates as you would any external resource.

Answer (score 1):

You really should separate these out, have a handlebars template that is separate from your html page and then load the template into the div.

so it would be

```
<div id="shoes">
</div>
```

and then have the separate file template that is loaded into that div.

```
'<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
  <ul class="shoesNav"> 
  {{#each this}}
      <li class="shoes">
        <a href="/{{name}}">{{name}} -- Price: {{price}} </a>
      </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

'

Comment: What would be the best way to load that template inside the div? With AJAX?

Comment: also what file extension would you give to the file template since there are not javascript files?

Comment: You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<ul>` like that, a `<ul>` only allows `<li>` elements as children: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/ul.html#ul-content-model

Comment: .html is fine or .cshtml if you are using asp.net. Just write javascript that when this script needs to load for whatever reason (button click, etc) you pass the template into the div. This stackoverflow question explains it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075132/loading-handlebars-js-template-from-external-html-file-shows-nothing

Answer (score 0):

in your main html file say: `main.html`

```html
<div id="myTarget"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    var context = { name : "XYZ", city : "Cape town" };
        var templateScript = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
        var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(templateScript);
        var html = theTemplate(context);
        console.log(html);
    
    $('#myTarget').append(html);
});
</script>

<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

in an external js file say: `myscripts.js`

```js
<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template" >
    <p> Hi, my name is @{{name}} and i live in @{{city}} </p>
</script>
```